# Best way to store two different color for element and change both when theme changed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

I'm try to understand how to store and change a two different color for button in light and dark theme:

```
/// light
ThemeData lightTheme() => ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    ...
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: const Color(0xffffffff), 
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff5063EE), // blue
      ),
    ),
);
/// dark
ThemeData darkTheme() => ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    ...
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: const Color(0xffffffff),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff40A076), // green 
      ),
    ),
);
```

When I change theme all it's fine, this button theme data applied for my button. But I have second TextButton with eg. orange color for light theme and X color for dark, now it's look like this:

```
/// first button
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text("first button"),
),
/// in second button widget
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text("second button"),
  style: Theme.of(context).textButtonTheme.style.copyWith(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
          (states) => Color(0xffF99543), // orange. <= need to change depends on theme.
        ),
      ),
),
```

How to change second button color dynamically depend on my theme? Where to store this color for light and dark themes?
What if I will have three different colors?...

Comment: The whole point of a theme is to have consistency across your UI. If you have different buttons that follow different rules, you need to make different themes that target each button separately (which, IMO, defeats the purpose of using themes in the first place).

Comment: @Abion47 you are right! but modern UI require different solutions, one button must be a different color. with all respect.

Comment: That doesn't change what I said. Having different colored buttons means creating different themes. (And, with all respect, modern UI trends have gravitated toward _more_ unified color palettes, not less, so having a green button and an orange button on the same page makes me dubious of your design choice.)

Comment: You can change the color of the button by checking `MediaQuery.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark`, but this is still going to be a clunky solution.

Comment: @Abion47 Yeap, "modern UI require different solutions" it's said my designer :D, "MediaQuery.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark" i understand, but tomorrow we add a new theme, what will we do? add one more if (theme == new theme) secondButton bg color = new color?...

Comment: You can use the `Theme` widget to set the theme of specific subsections of the widget tree but if you really get to the point where you have many different themes for different sections of the app, you'd probably want to think about making a custom theme repository class (and maybe start questioning your designer's theme choices).

Comment: @Abion47 theme repository! this is should be right way thanks! ps. designer give us just light theme, but client may want have a different themes, and we think about place where we can manage all themes

Comment: Don't plan for features you don't need right now. YAGNI is an invaluable development philosophy for preventing feature creep in development projects. Unless your clients have expressly requested the ability to specify custom themes (or you realistically expect them to in the *near* future), I wouldn't bother.